# How to mount encrypted rootfs using uboot without entering password on beaglebone black

Tags: debian, encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption, beaglebone

I am using Beaglebone Black as my board.
I want to encrypt internal eMMC of BBB.(rootfs)
I am using debian.
there is two partition on eMMC.
1st for boot :vfat 16 (which include MLO and u-boot.img )
2nd for rootfs: ext4

now I need to encrypt rootfs , but it should mounted automatically without entering password( decryption key may be hard-coded in uboot source)

I am following https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black to compile Linux kernel. 
I am good in application development. but I have never work with uboot.

Please help me.

thanks in advance.